# programmatic access on .skin file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to find a way to check if .skin file have a style defined. The idea is to make the control to use a default SkinId if the one defined in definition doesn't exist in styles. Any help will be appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: Did you try reading the file as a normal text file using System.IO.StreamReader or System.IO.File.ReadAllText?

Comment: I had a thought of that but I was wondering if there is any proper way to intercept/handle these skin styles.

Comment: I guess there's no other way.